# New command within glossaries ›first‹ needs to be protected?

Tags: glossaries, protected-macro

Consider following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xspace}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\BC{\,v.\,Chr\@ifnextchar.{}{.\relax\@\xspace}}
\newcommand\AD{\,n.\,Chr\@ifnextchar.{}{.\relax\@\xspace}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Augustus}{%
  name={\textbf{Augustus}},% 
  description={Imperator 
    Caesar Divi Filius Augustus, geboren 63\BC, gestorben 14\AD, regierte von 27\BC bis 14\AD.},
  first={Augustus (27\protect\BC--14\protect\AD)}
}

\begin{document}
  \gls{Augustus}

  \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

All is fine and works as expected:

[image]

But I dont understand why the `protect`-commands in `first={Augustus (27\protect\BC--14\protect\AD)}` are necessary since I do not need them in `description`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fields are expanded by default and some aren't. These are described in more detail in section [4.4 Expansion](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:expansion) in the `glossaries` manual, but essentially the `name`, `description` and `symbol` fields aren't expanded by default and all others are. The `sort` key is an exception which is covered by the `sanitizesort` package option. Those fields that are expanded must have fragile commands protected.

To switch off all expansion use `\glsnoexpandfields`. Specific fields can have the expansion switched off with `\glssetnoexpandfield{`*field*`}`. This individual setting overrides the `\glsexpandfields` setting.